# Upgrading to struts 2.3.15.1 does not set HashMap values on action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I upgraded from 2.1.6 to 2.3.15.1 because of the security fixes available in the latest version. However, now the form field values are not posted to the Action class. 
Basically, I populate the `HashMap` `props` from the JSP into the Action class, when the form is submitted. When I upgraded the struts version to 2.3.15.1 this does not work. There has been no code change. When I debugged the code, I noticed that the `setProps` method is not invoked. Is this not allowed anymore. Is there any workaround? As soon as I revert the struts library changes, everything works perfect. Please help.

Here is how my code looks like:

**Action class**:

```
    private Map<String, Wall> props;

    public void prepare(){
          //fill up props map here.
        }
    public String view(){
        return INPUT;
    }

    public String save(){
        myService.setProps(props);
        return INPUT;
    }

    public void setProps(Map<String, Wall> props) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public Map<String, Wall> getProps() {
        return props;
    }
```

**JSP**:

```
<s:iterator value="props.entrySet()" id="prop" status="propStatus">
    <s:textfield name="props['%{#prop.key}'].value" value="%{#prop.value.value}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been huge changes since Struts 2.1.6. Struts 2 will not create objects for you if you don't explicitly tell it to do. The `prepare` method calls before the `params` interceptor sets `props` to the action, and you commented that you populate the map

> //fill up props map here.

not surprisingly, that Struts not call that setter `setProps` because it already contains a map instance. So, it simply calls `getProps`. Then it should set the indexed property values to the map. But it doesn't know a type of the object that is an element of the collection to convert to, and if it should create a new object for element if it's `null`. By putting annotations on the `props` field it should solve the problem populating a map on submit.

```
@Element(value = Wall.class)
@CreateIfNull(value = true)
private Map<String, Wall> props = new HashMap<>();
```

I guess the key it will determine automatically. The same could be done if you specify it in `Action-conversion.properties`

```
Element_props=Wall
CreateIfNull_props=true
```

Next your JSP could be replaced to

```
<s:iterator value="props">
    <s:textfield name="props['%{key}'].value" />
</s:iterator>
```

And last the `Wall` class you haven't posted, should look like

```
public class Wall {
  String value;
  //getter and setter here
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clean iterator suggestion. So, it is not an issue if the submitted property name is props['a.b.c'].value? I had something similar, and I chaged the property name to props['abc'].value and everything works fine. In my case, setting up the map in the prepare method is important because many actions depend on it.

Comment: @Nik It doesn't matter which `props`'s key you keep in the map. You might also use prepare to populate your map, in this case I didn't understand you question because you didn't say what values you need to post. IMO I'd never use prepare to populate collections because in this case I need to put `params` interceptor before `prepare`.

Comment: So I removed the map from prepare method, added the annotations as mentioned above, still I don't see the set method being called and the map is empty. Not sure what I am missing. My action is validationaware, and it has validate() method too. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. With the new Struts versions parameter names are more restrictive. In my case, I had parameter names such as `props['1.2.3'], props['a.b.c'] or props['a-b-c']`. These were filtered out by the new struts. Here is the link which explains this: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/s2-009.html. The very last part explains why the collections might stop working.

I changed the acceptParamNames in the interceptor stack to `<param name="acceptParamNames">\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\['\w+(\-\w+)*'\]))*</param>` and it solved the issue. I got rid of the `props['a.b.c']` property names so the above regex does not cover it, but it does cover `props['a-b-c']`.

Thanks to @Roman C for coming forward to help me.

Comment: I was facing the same issue while upgrading struts from 2.0.11 to 2.3.16. Solved using above implementation. Thanks!