# How to pass id of an item as an hidden field in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using the following code to show a list of products and allow users to edit their details. Users are able to change any of the fields and submit the form but I need to know how to pass the ID of each product using a hidden field?

**JSP page**

```
 <s:form name="updatePro" action="updateProducts">
                <s:iterator value="listOfProducts" status="element">
                    <s:textfield name="elements[%{#element.index}].ID" value="%{ID}" theme="simple"/>
                    <s:textfield name="elements[%{#element.index}].status" value="%{status}" theme="simple"/>
                    <s:textfield name="elements[%{#element.index}].price" value="%{price}" theme="simple"/>
                    <hr/>
                </s:iterator>
                 <s:submit></s:submit>
            </s:form>
```

**Java class**

```
private List<Product> elements;
 public MyClass() {
        this.element = new <Product> ArrayList();
    }

   getter and setter go here

   public void updateProducts() {
        System.out.println("Update is here");
        System.out.println("Size is >>>>> " + this.element.size());
    }
```

Comment: your  code is a bit confusing to me,`listOfProducts` this is source source of iteration and than you are submiting it to same list in you action class, but your action is quite different than that.Also program to interface and better use `List` than `ArrayList`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi so what do you suggest? should I remove the listOfProducts from name of each textfield?

Comment: Are you able to show products with this code..?

Comment: yes I have updated the code but still the size is zero

Comment: have you tried with `element[%{#element.index}].status` etc, please note that `element` before `[` represents your ArrayList.

Comment: it shows the correct size but all the time returns the total size of products even if I change a field of just one of the products

Comment: not sure what you mean by showing correct size but returns total size of products?

Comment: I mean need it to just show the number of products that their fields have been changed, not the total size of products

Comment: you mean you want to know only about products who have been changed? like you showing 10 products and if only 2 has been changed at UI, you want to show only those 2 products?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028172/upgrading-to-struts-2-3-15-1-does-not-set-hashmap-values-on-action-class/18030697#18030697

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes I need it to just send the objects of those two not all objects so I wont need to figure out which ones have changed.

Comment: Have you checked out: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/tag-reference.html the "hidden" tag seems promising.