# update to struts2.3.15.1 breaks dot notation in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

We updated to Struts 2.3.15.1 for security purposes.  When we did we noticed that we lost some ability to set values using the dot notation method in the jsp.  If we have a map that takes the Foo class and Foo has a Bar class, we had been previously successful in setting the Bar class for Foo using a hidden field.  When we updated, the Bar class is now coming across as null whereas before the Bar class - in the sample below - would have been created for Foo and given an id value of 12. I know this is similar to the question on 2.3.15.1 not setting hashmap values but the suggestions in that post have been tried without success:

[[Upgrading to struts 2.3.15.1 does not set HashMap values on action class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028172/upgrading-to-struts-2-3-15-1-does-not-set-hashmap-values-on-action-class][1])

Is there a syntax that we need to be using in our jsp to get the previous results with the new version of Struts?

**Class Foo**

```
private Bar bar;

private String name;

public Bar getBar(){

return bar;

}

public void setBar(Bar bar){

this.bar = bar;

}

public String getName(){

return name;

}

public void setName(String name){

this.name = name;

}
```

**Class Bar**

```
private int id

public int getId(){

return id;

}

public void setId(int id){

this.id = id;

}
```

**Class ActionClass**{

```
private Map<String, Foo> userInputMap;

public Map<String, Foo> getUserInputMap(){
return userInputMap;
}

public void setUserInputMap(Map<String, Foo>, userInputMap){
this.userInputMap = userInputMap;
}

}
```

**input.jsp**

```
<s:hidden name="foo.userInputMap<'first_map_key'>.bar.id" value="12" />

<s:textarea name="foo.userInputMap<'first_map_key'>.name />
```

Comment: Always INDENT code for a succesful living.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish to circle back, the original poster is a coworker of mine.

We did finally find the answer to this issue.  The issue is not what we thought, the issue was that the request parameters were to long.  S2-011 (see https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-011.html) decreased the request parameters length to 100 characters long.

The names in the fields are being used as the request parameters, in in some cases we had names for the fields exciding 120 characters.

By putting the following code into our struts.xml file the issue was resolved.

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
      <param name="paramNameMaxLength">150</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:iterator value="userInputMap" >
    <s:hidden   name="userInputMap['%{key}'].bar.id" />
    <s:textarea name="userInputMap['%{key}'].name"   />
</s:iterator>
```