# Access action class map in java script within ftl

Tags: javascript, struts2, freemarker

We need to access an instance map defined in struts action class (it has get/set methods). We need to populated that map dynamically. We generate code to populate the map at runtime using a java script based on some user input. We are using freemarker as template.

Java script code within ftl looks like:

```
innerHTML += '<input class="isn" onChange="validateTag(this);" name="serialsInp[\'' + listing + '\']" value=""/>';
```

Here `serialsInp` is `HashMap<String, String>` and `listing` is java script variable. Above code renders a text field. The expectation is when user enters text in this text field, serialsInp should be populated with 'listing' as key and user entered value as value.

Is this the correct way of accessing maps in javascript/ftl?

Comment: Scripts are executed on the client-side, even if they are javascripts.

Comment: freemarker tags/variables are inteerpreted on the server-side but you're generating freemarker code on the client-side, too late!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem was form parameters. The map key in our case contains '-', which is disallowed due to security reasons.

The issue got resolved once we change 'params' interceptor to allow '-' in parameter names by adding following code in struts.xml

```
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="acceptParamNames">\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\['\w+(\-\w+)*'\]))*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
```

Reference [202](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/s2-009.html) & [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028172/upgrading-to-struts-2-3-15-1-does-not-set-hashmap-values-on-action-class)